# Python recognize strings of numbers with K, M, G, or k, m, g, or KB, MB, GB, etc as filesizes for comparison or math

Tags: string, byte, filesize, megabyte

Using Python 3.8 or newer. I have a Pandas dataframe of numbers like below, and I need to convert each item that is not a percent into bytes or some custom format in order to compare and/or do math on them. Is there an existing library or relatively fast method to do this?

```
425M    410M    6.2M    99%    5.8k   51k   10%
1.0K    1.0K      0B   100%       0     0  100%
4.0K    4.0K      0B   100%       1     0  100%
7.8G    1.1G    6.1G    15%     405  1.1M    0%
94G      26G     60G    31%     68k   13M    1%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well solved my own problem. Couldn't find any code out there so I wrote my own class. I'm sure there's tons of improvements that can be made. It's in my github: https://github.com/KyferEz/DataUnits